# How to remove before and after string in php

Tags: php

Here is my string so far

```
Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day - Feb 14th|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you
```

I want below output

```
Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you
```

As per above output i want to remove  `- Feb 14th` from the string.

Note:-  **`- Feb 14th`** this string would be dynamic like some time it would be **-  DEC 25TH** OR  **- 27th Nov** etc ..
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: tried `str_replace()` ?

Comment: so what is constant? Is allways an integer to remove?

Comment: It is actually the occasion month i want to remove from string ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your update, this will work:

```
$str = 'Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day - Feb 14th|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you'
$a = strpos($str,'-');
$b = strpos($str, '|', $a);
if ($b) {
    $c = $b - $a;
    echo substr_replace($str, '', $a - 1, $c + 1);
}
else {
    echo strstr($str,' -', true);
}
```

Output:

```
Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you
```

Comment: @baao good job with the `strpos`! (BTW: Not sure if OP want's a Space at the end of: `Valentines Day ` maybe you could corret that :D)

Comment: But suppose if this is the result then Occasions=>Love & Romance||Anniversary||Thinking of you|#|Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Wife||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Roses||Valentines Day - Feb 14th

Comment: @user2818254 hehe, good point. edited it. now this is not a problem any more

Comment: there is some bug i think in the code because when i execute my code and export into csv, in some string u, s etc is also removed. :(

Comment: If the Lines are like you've written in your question, this is not possible

Comment: Once bug i notice when i execute above code. Warning: Wrong parameter count for strstr() in //////////////// when it goes under else condition.

Comment: Seems like you have strings without -. You won't get a function that works with strings which aren't within a certain pattern

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.2.9 actually... :(

Comment: I have changed else condition to else {
    $categoryOcc =  explode('-',$categoryOccassion);
 $categoryOccassion = $categoryOcc[0]; 
}

Comment: Works now? Excellent!

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
$str = "Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day - Feb 14th|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you";
echo $str . "<br />";
$str = preg_replace('/\s-(.*?)\|/', '|', $str);
echo $str . "<br />";
```

Output:

```
Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day - Feb 14th|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you
Birthdays=>Birthday||Birthday for Girlfriend|#|Valentines Day=>Valentine Combos||Valentine Roses||Valentines Day|#|Occasions=>Thinking of you
```

Comment: @user2818254 So the string is sometimes: `- Feb 14th` and sometimes: `CHRISTMAS - DEC 25TH ` with the chrismas? Also is it every time at the same position?

Comment: I want to remove after -

Comment: @user2818254 updated my answer! now it matches everything from: `<space>-<until>|`